# JS Lambda scoping with async.parallel call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am unable to capture a variable into the lambda function from its outer scope. When I run this code it executes with the same variable. I am passing the variable into the function, but I am obviously misunderstanding how scoping works with lambda.

```
  // Add tasks to async_tasks
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    var task = function(task_callback){

      // I want to capture i and pass it to the function
      (function(i){

        exports.defaultCarWithId(connection, i, function(err, data){
          if (err) {
            console.log('error in query: ' + err.stack);
            fCallback("[Internal Server Error]", null);
            return;
          }

          task_callback();

        });

      })(i);

    };

    async_tasks.push(task);

  }

  // execute tasks
  async.parallel(async_tasks, function(err, results){

    fCallback(null, user);
    return;

  });
```

Comment: I don't see any lambda functions here?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Seems I may have confused that with an anonymous function?

Comment: That may be the case. Lambdas in JS (Fat arrow syntax) are would be like `async.parellel(async_tasks, (err, results) => { fCallback(null, user); return; });`

Comment: You need to capture i in a closure for the task; not within the task function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the outer function:

```
var task = (function(i){
    return function(task_callback){
        exports.defaultCarWithId(connection, i, function(err, data){
          if (err) {
            console.log('error in query: ' + err.stack);
            fCallback("[Internal Server Error]", null);
            return;
          }

          task_callback();
        });
    };
})(i);

async_tasks.push(task);
```

or pass `i` as argument and bind it:

```
var task = function(i, task_callback){
    exports.defaultCarWithId(connection, i, function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        console.log('error in query: ' + err.stack);
        fCallback("[Internal Server Error]", null);
        return;
      }

      task_callback();

    });
};

async_tasks.push(task.bind(null, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically two mistakes i can see:

1. You are re-declaring the variable i inside for loop. Name it something different.
2. Create closure something like this:

   Var task = (function(i) {
   return function(task_callback) {
   // Your logic
   };
   })(i);

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what exactly you are calling lambda here but if you want to bind context in async you need to use method each or one of new array methods of a framework. [Have a look to docs](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each)